# Django: How to "extend" Group creation using Signals?

Tags: python, django

I am not sure if I am asking the right question. But is it possible to add "behaviors" when creating a Group in Django? I want want to create directories/files after creating a Group in the admin panel.

The "additional" behaviors (creating the directory/file) can happen after the Group was successfully added in the database or after the POST was successful (?).

Thanks!
Wenbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Catch](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals) the `post_save` signal [for the `Group` model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders), then do your processing in there.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the reply. But I am having a really hard time grasping the idea and where to place the code, etc.